# How can i click on a <button> with sélénium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I have this Html code:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to cart" class="button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to cart</span></span></button></pre>
```

And in my code i used xpath to find the element and className also but it's not working at all.

```
WebElement addtocart = driver.findElement(By.className("button"));
addtocart.click();
```

If you can help me i'll very grateful guys !

Comment: Is that the only button on the page?

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Comment: @BravastStudio make sure to mark the answer that solves your problem. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply grab the button whose title is Add to cart and click it.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[title='Add to cart']")).click();
```

Comment: thank u very much ! really i was stuck on this like for hours.